# I am trying to solve this leetcode problem

Tags: java, fibonacci

Question :

Given the number k, return the minimum number of Fibonacci numbers whose sum is equal to k, whether a Fibonacci number could be used multiple times.

The Fibonacci numbers are defined as:

```
F1 = 1
F2 = 1
Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2 , for n > 2.
```

It is guaranteed that for the given constraints we can always find such fibonacci numbers that sum k.

Link to question:

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-minimum-number-of-fibonacci-numbers-whose-sum-is-k/

Example :
Input: k = 7
Output: 2
Explanation: The Fibonacci numbers are: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...
For k = 7 we can use 2 + 5 = 7.

```
    class Solution {
        public int findMinFibonacciNumbers(int count) {
            PriorityQueue<Integer> num=new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
          
            int i1=1,i2=1;
            num.add(i1);
            num.add(i2);
            int k=count;
            int i3=0;
            k=k-2;
            int res=0;
            while(k>=1){
                i3=i2+i1;
                num.add(i3);
                int temp=i2;
                i2=i3;
                i1=temp;
                k--;
            }
            while(count!=0){
                int n=num.poll();
                if(n<=count)
                {      res++;
                       count-=n;
                }
            }
            return res;
            
        }
    }
```

It says wrong output for 'input=3'. I generated the fibonacci series and traversed from highest number to find numbers less than or equal to sum. It will be really helpful if somebody helps me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You're `poll`ing the queue, ***REMOVING** elements from it*, but you probably wanted to use `peek`

Comment: Some simple debugging with print statements should show you the problem. A debugger might be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use recursion for this problem.

This'll pass through:

```
class Solution {
    public int findMinFibonacciNumbers(int k) {
        if (k < 2)
            return k;

        int first = 1;
        int second = 1;

        while (second <= k) {
            second += first;
            first = second - first;
        }

        return 1 + findMinFibonacciNumbers(k - first);
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-minimum-number-of-fibonacci-numbers-whose-sum-is-k/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>). Overall, we would like to avoid anything that might become controversial for interviews.
- There are also other similar [platforms](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-HackerRank-or-LeetCode), which you might have to become familiar with, in case you'd be interviewing with specific companies that would use those platforms.

#### If you are practicing for [contests](https://leetcode.com/contest/)<sup>[1](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf)</sup>:

- Just code as fast as you can, almost everything else is very trivial.
- For [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions, brute force algorithms usually get accepted. For interviews, brute force is less desired, especially if the question would be an [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) level.
- For [medium](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Medium) and [hard](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Hard) questions, about 90% of the time, brute force algorithms fail mostly with [Time Limit Exceeded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) (TLE) and less with Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE) errors.
- Contestants are ranked based on an algorithm explained [here](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/468851/New-Contest-Rating-Algorithm-(Coming-Soon)).